# Проблема с Windows-путями в Python-скрипте

Tags: python, windows

Мне нужно написать Python-скрипт для копирования одного файла в сетевую папку. Файл этот - 7z архив, папка примонтирована в системе как жесткий диск. ОС - Windows 7. 
Я написал скрипт, он работает, если запустить из консоли руками. Но когда я засовываю его в Планировщик заданий, он при запуске завершается с кодом 0x1. Чтобы понять, в чем вообще ошибка, пришлось запускать .py через bat-файл и перенаправлять поток ошибок (2>>): ни один путь из моего скрипта не воспринимается системой правильно. Вот код на текущий момент:

```
import shutil
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import logging

def xerox(source_file, target_file):
    shutil.copy2(source_file, target_file)

WEEKDAY = str(datetime.now().weekday())
TODAY = str(datetime.now().date())
FILEPATH = r'B:'
FILENAME="\copying_messages_" + TODAY + ".log"
LOGFILE=FILEPATH+FILENAME
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOGFILE, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Execution started: " + TODAY)
logging.info("Initialization")
source_filepath = r'C:\dump'
source_filename = "\base_" + WEEKDAY + ".7z"
source_file = source_filepath + source_filename
target_filepath = r'B:'
target_filename = "\my_backup_" + WEEKDAY + ".7z"
target_file = target_filepath + target_filename
logging.info("Source file is %s, target file is %s", source_file, target_file)
logging.info("Start the copying process")
xerox(source_file, target_file)
logging.info("Sequence completed")
```

В тексте ошибки говорится, что файл "B:\\copying_messages_3.log" не найден.
Я пробовал оборачивать пути в Path(), результат такой же. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Для начала, перед всеми строками, где есть обратные слеши, добавьте r (не только там где начало пути прописано).

Comment: Добавил. Попробовал и с двойными кавычками, и с одинарными. Результат прежний, текст ошибки: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'B:\\copying_messages_2018-10-25.log'

Comment: А файл-то есть такой? Используй os.path.join().

Comment: 2 - если ругается на файл лога, проверьте, будет ли работать без логгирования. 3 - проверьте как назначены права для сетевой папки (чтение-запись должны быть включены для всех или для нужного пользователя) 4 - попробуйте обращаться к сетевой папке через имя или IP компьютера, на котором она расположена, а не через сетевой диск.

Comment: Без лога пробовал, тогда ругаться начинает на пути файлов. Права перепроверял, чтение-запись разрешены.
4 совет помог. Вместо пути прописал айпишник, все завелось. Большое спасибо за помощь.